# window.close closes the postbacked child window and a copy of child window still appears

Tags: javascript

I am opening a child window using the below code:

```js
window.showModalDialog("FileUpload.aspx", "FileUpload", 
    "center:yes;resizeable=yes;dialogHeight:300px;dialogWidth:600px;");
```

I save the file uploaded in the child window(FileUpload.aspx)in its code behind FileUpload.vb page.
Since server side code, its postbacking and opening a new browser .

After my functionality in the child window, when I close it using below code,

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

it is closing the new browser opened because of postback but a copy of the same child window is still open when returning to the parent page.

I want to close all the instances of this child window.

Comment: I don't believe you need to call `window.open` on '_self'.  This was just an ie hack to make the browser believe you had privileges to close the current window since you were the owner.  Since you're already the one who opened it with `showModalDialog` you can just call `window.close();`

Answer (score 0):

The [`showModalDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method will freeze JavaScript execution on the parent window until the dialog that it opens has closed, so we can rule out that as the reason why your second window opens.  When `FileUpload.aspx` posts back from the server, it should work the same way as modeless aspx postbacks.

I think you should be able to get rid of the `window.open()` method and you should be fine.

**Parent window:**

```
window.showModalDialog("FileUpload.aspx", "FileUpload", 
    "center:yes;resizeable=yes;dialogHeight:300px;dialogWidth:600px;");
```

The **Child window** will call this when it's done.

```
window.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle for the response. The modal dialog is functioning as expected but since there is a server side code written for it, it is opening a new browser and performing the server side action. When I close the window, its closing the new window tht has opened but another copy seems still appeared

Comment: The server side code shouldn't need to open a new browser on its own unless you're telling it to.  Can you post some relevant sections of server side code since you suspect that where the issue is?  Better yet, can you upload a solution that reproduces the problem with the least code possible?